# How can i send data from ESP32 to C# VIsual Studio with WIFI

Tags: c#, esp32

Here i have a code for connecting to my wifi

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* WIFI_NAME = "SARAN";
const char* WIFI_PASS = "00000000";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
              
              // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_NAME);

  WiFi.begin(WIFI_NAME,WIFI_PASS);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

// Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {
}
```

And i try to create window form app C# in Visual Studio to receive a DATA from ESP32. Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: and, do you want to use UDP or TCP? if TCP, which one should be the server? do you want it to work over Internet or only in local network? see the examples of the WiFi library.

Comment: I want to use TCP and C# would be the server

Comment: See msdn socket examples for sending TCP data on internet (WIFI) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: WiFiClient is a client socket in Arduino

Answer (score -2):

Connecting to WIFI is always a kind of a pain because the communication requires local Wi-Fi network, SSID & password - all can change. I would like to suggest another direction: have another ESP device (can be WEMOS, ESP8266 or ESP32) connected with USB to the computer you use for C# code developing. The ESP32 will communicate with this device with ESPnow, which doesn't require local Wi-Fi network. The "cost" of this approach is of course another ESP device, the benefit is much bigger: you can move it from one computer to another, between rooms, houses or even at open doors.

I use it for exactly same target as you need - connect ESP32 to a windows 10 computer, developing with C#.